# Codeigniter - session login bug

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, xampp

Hi I'm coding the login and register module
I found bug about session like this.
 First I do login  then I close page. After that I re-open page and put path url, and this would occur.....,

- If I put path url "localhost/codeigniter/index.php/some-controller" , It will show the viewpage in pre-login state.
- But if I click something to change page, It will show after-login state  and the path url change from "localhost/codeignite/index.php/some-controller" to "[::1]/codeigniter/index.php/some-controller"

  - so If I try to put the [::1] instead of localhost  in path url at first  It will show the after-login state too. what's happening? why I cannot use localhost? It seem, it does not have session if I use localhost.  or is this a bug on xampp mysql??

---

```
<?php   ///////////////view/header.php///////////
                if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
                {
                    echo "Welcome!, " . $this->session->userdata('username');
                    echo  anchor('login/logout','Sign Out') ."</span>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo anchor('login','Log in');
                    echo anchor('register/index','Register') ;
                }
            ?>
```

Login Controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Login extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
        }
        public function index()
        {

            $this->load->view('header');

            $this->load->view('regislogin/loginform');

            $this->load->view('footer');
        }

        public function login_validation()
        {
            $this->load->view('header');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|trim|callback_validate_credentials');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5|trim');

            if($this->form_validation->run()) //==TRUE
            {
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('login/userPage');     
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('regislogin/loginform');
            }


        }

        public function userPage() 
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) //if==true
            {
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('regislogin/success');

            }
            else
            {

            }           
        }


        public function validate_credentials()
        {
            //$this->load->model('login_model');  //autoload already
            if($this->login_model->can_login()) //if can_login == true
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials','Username/Password Incorrect');
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function logout()
        {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

Login Model

```
<?php
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function can_login()
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password'))); 

        $query = $this->db->get('member');

        if($query->num_rows() == 1)  //if Found 1 match
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

register controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Register extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
    }
    public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->view('header');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[6]);


        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('regislogin/register_view');
        }
        else
        {
            $key = md5(uniqid());
            $this->load->library('email', array('mailtype'=>'html'));//default mailtype is 'text'
            $this->email->from('supanat_thana@hotmail.com', "Webmaster");
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->subject("Confirm your account");
            $message = "<p>Thank you for register!</p>";
            $message .= "<p><a href='".base_url()."register/register_activate/$key'>Click Here</a> เพื่อยืนยันบัญ๙ีของคุณ </p>";
            $this->email->message($message);



            if($this->register_model->add_temp_user($key))
            {
                if($this->email->send())
                {
                    $data['emailstr'] = "Please activate your account by email";
                } 
                else
                {
                    $data['emailfail'] = "could not send the email.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Problem: cannot insert to out database";
            }

            $this->load->view('regislogin/success', $data);
        }


    }

    public function register_activate($key)
    {
        if($this->register_model->is_key_valid($key))
        {
            if($newuser = $this->register_model->addMember($key))
            { 

                $data = array(
                    'username' => $newuser,
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('login/userPage');

                echo "successfully activate account <br/>";
                echo anchor('home', 'back to Home');
            } else echo "sorry cannot activate account";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "invalid key";
        }
    }


}
```

register model

```
<?php
class Register_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function add_temp_user($key)
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'key' => $key
        );

        $query = $this->db->insert('temp_user', $data);
        if($query) {return true;}
        else {return false;}
    }

    public function is_key_valid($key)
    {
        $this->db->where('key', $key);
        $query = $this->db->get('temp_user');

        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{return false;}
    }

    public function addMember($key)
    {
        $this->db->where('key', $key);
        $temp_users = $this->db->get('temp_user');

        if($temp_users)
        {
            $row = $temp_users->row();

            $data = array(
                'username' => $row->username,
                'password' => $row->password,
                'email' => $row->email,
                'phone' => $row->phone
            );

            $did_adduser = $this->db->insert('member', $data);
        }
        if($did_adduser)
        {
            $this->db->where('key', $key);
            $this->db->delete('temp_user');
            return $data['username'];
        } else{return false;}
    }

    public function isUserExist()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $query = $this->db->get('member');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function isEmailExist()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $query = $this->db->get('member','temp_user');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

view/regislogin/success.php

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Register </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if($this->input->post("btn"))
    {
        echo "<h3>Thank you for your registration</h3>";
        echo $emailstr."<br/><br/>";
        if(isset($emailfail)) {echo $emailfail."<br/><br/>";} else{}
        echo anchor('home', 'กลับสู่หน้าหลัก');

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h3>Successful Login</h3>";
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "Welcome!, ". $this->session->userdata('username');
        echo "</pre>";

        echo anchor('login/logout', 'Logout')."<br/>"; 
        echo anchor('home', 'Back to Home');
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

view/loginregis/loginform.php

```
<div class="loginbox">
    <?php echo form_open('login/login_validation');?>
        <h2> Login </h2>
        <ul id='login'>
            <li>
                Username: <br>
                <input type='text' name='username'>
            </li>
            <li>
                Password:<br>
                <input type='password' name='password'>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
                <input type='submit' name='btn2' value='Log in'>
            </li>
            <li>
                <br>
                <?php echo anchor("register/index","Register");?>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

view/regislogin/register_view.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>

    <div id="wrapper_regis">
        <div id="header_regis">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        </div>

    <?php echo form_open('register');?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"  value=""/></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Password : </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""/></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirmed Password : </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass_confirm" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" value=""/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Phone : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone"  value=""/></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="btn" value="สมัครสมาชิก"/>

    <?php echo form_close();?>
    </div>
```

MySQL Table

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

at config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');
$autoload['model'] = array('register_model','login_model');
```

Comment: did not seen an error in code . this might be caused by conflicted name of session

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your session is working or not ,
Also are you adding proper condition on controller and logout .
Better to add a single condition in hooks so that you dont have to write it every controller.
Also can you provide some code snippet to look  more .

Answer (score 1):

I imported you code and it is working as it should be .
Please just do below things 
1. add a blank array $data = array(); inside Register.php(controller) in index function.
2. In login controller inside function userPage ,Else condition add a line to redirect it on login page

```
   public function userPage() 
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) //if==true
        {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('regislogin/success');

        }
        else
        {
            redirect('login');
        }           
    }
```

You have any concern then can you please share your page name where you are getting errors .

Comment: Can you please give me flow ,Like you are going to index.php/login  then index.php/userPage etc , SO that i can understand whole scenario

Comment: 1. home.php   <--- sorry I'm not put viewfile here  but  my view/home.php is just a test page so you can create yourself.   2.go to loginform page  3.input username password   4.header will change to welcome! username  5.  close page  6. open page  put any url path  localhost/codeigniter...........  not [::1]/codeigniter/.....  such as "localhost/codeigniter/index.php/register   and then you will see the header does not show welcome! username message  anymore.

Comment: That i have created , But not getting that which flow is giving you error .Just want to know what flow you are doing

Comment: 7.if put url  like this "[::1]/codeigniter/index.php/some_controller such as home,register"  you will see the result is show welcome! username  on header correctly.

Comment: In conclusion,  if I use "[::1]" instead of "localhost"  in path url , the session will work correctly.  and yeah if I click to other page  it will change localhost to [::1] automatically and work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

ok I solve it.
in folder path config/config.php
set this
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/foldername';